# Traverse an array diagonally

Tags: java, arrays, traversal

I have a large array of arbitrary size. It's a square array. I'm trying to grasp how to traverse it diagonally like a `/` rather than a `\` (what I already know how to do). I have the following code thus far:

```
char[][] array = new char[500][500];
//array full of random letters
String arrayLine = "";
for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        for (???) {
            arrayLine = arrayLine + array[???][???];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arrayLine);
}
```

I have three loops, because this is how I did the other diagonal:

```
for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < array.length-y-x; z++) {
            arrayLine = arrayLine + array[y+z][x+z];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arrayLine);
}
```

In my attempts, I keep going outside the boundaries and get an ElementOutOfBounds exception. Say the array is as below (a 3x3 instead of 500x500):

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

I want to print out the following as strings:

```
A
BD
CEG
FH
I
```

A previous SO question had a similar problem with integer arrays, and the solution is based off of the sum of array elements. But I'm working with chars, so I can't think of a methodology to get it.

Comment: Think about what happens when you add `i` and `j` for each point in the array. You'll notice that B, `(0, 1)` and D, `(1, 0)` both sum to 1. Consider this application when figuring this out. Note: it is also important to check bounds.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. A = 0,0, B + D = 1,1, C + E + G = 3,3, then 3,3, then 2,2...

Comment: by `i and j` I referred to the coordinates. C, E and G would have a value of 2. F and H would have a value of 3. I's value is 4.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect closer to what I'm trying to get. Your advice is sound, but I guess my oversimplification got in the way of me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Think about the coordinates of the cells:

```
. 0 1 2
0 A B C
1 D E F
2 G H I
```

For any diagonal, all of the elements have something in common: the sum of an element's coordinates is a constant.  Here are the constants:

```
0 = 0+0 (A)
1 = 1+0 (B) = 0+1 (D)
2 = 2+0 (C) = 1+1 (E) = 0+2 (G)
3 = 2+1 (F) = 1+2 (H)
4 = 2+2 (I)
```

The minimum constant is the smallest coordinate sum, 0.  The maximum constant is the largest coordinate sum.  Since each coordinate component can go up to `array.length - 1`, the maximum constant is `2 * (array.length - 1)`.

So the thing to do is iterate over the constants.  For each constant, iterate over the elements whose coordinates sum to the constant.  This is probably the simplest approach:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= 2 * (array.length - 1); ++k) {
    for (int y = 0; y < array.length; ++y) {
        int x = k - y;
        if (x < 0 || x >= array.length) {
            // Coordinates are out of bounds; skip.
        } else {
            System.out.print(array[y][x]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

However, that will end up iterating over a lot of out-of-bounds coordinates, because it always iterates over all possible `y` coordinates, even though only one diagonal contains all possible `y` coordinates.  Let's change the `y` loop so it only visits the `y` coordinates needed for the current `k`.

One condition for out-of-bounds coordinates is `x < 0`.  Substitute the definition of `x` and solve:

```
x < 0
k - y < 0
k < y
y > k
```

So when `y > k`, `x` will be negative.  Thus we only want to loop while `y <= k`.

The other condition for out-of-bounds coordinates is `x >= array.length`.  Solve:

```
x >= array.length
k - y >= array.length
k - array.length >= y
y <= k - array.length
```

So when `y <= k - array.length`, `x` will be too large.  Thus we want to start `y` at 0 or `k - array.length + 1`, whichever is larger.

```
for (int k = 0; k <= 2 * (array.length - 1); ++k) {
    int yMin = Math.max(0, k - array.length + 1);
    int yMax = Math.min(array.length - 1, k);
    for (int y = yMin; y <= yMax; ++y) {
        int x = k - y;
        System.out.print(array[y][x]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Note: I have only proven this code correct.  I have not tested it.

Comment: How would you edit your method to make it go the opposite way?
\ instead of a /

Comment: In that case, all of the elements of a diagonal have this in common: the difference in coordinates (`y-x`) is a constant.  The remainder of the answer is much the same.

Comment: Which part would i have to change to change the direction in his method? (his original question)

Comment: If you need more help, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler way is to check the sum if indexes are equals to the array.length = 1; for diagonalRight and for diagonalLeft just check if i is equals j

Example:

digonalLeft sums \ of matrix, because (0,0) (1,1) (2,2) makes the diagonal.
diagonalRight sums / of matrix, because (0+2) = (1+1) = (2+0) = 2 and 2 is the array.length - 1.

```
long diagonalLeft = 0;
long diagonalRight = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.lenth - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length -1; j++) {
        if (i == j) digonalLeft += array[i][j];
        if (i + j == array.length - 1) diagonalRight += array[i][j];
    }    
}
```

Comment: For the loops it should be <= and not < as you're subtracting -1 from the array length.