# Traversing a 2D array matrix diagonally from bottom left to upper right

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have a 3x4 matrix represented by a 2D array:

```
. 0  1  2  3
0 a  c  f  i   
1 b  e  h  k
2 d  g  j  l
```

and my approach to traverse the diagonal slice was to treat each slice as a sum, like this:

```
a = (0+0) = 0
b,c = (0+1),(1+0) = 1
d,e,f = (0+2),(1+1),(2+0) = 2
g,h,i = (1+2),(2+1),(3+0) = 3
j, k = (2+2),(3+1) = 4
l = (3+2) = 5
```

However, my code right now prints it in the opposite way that I want it to, which is from upper right to bottom left.

Current Output is:

```
acbfedihgkjl
```

Desired Output is:

```
abcdefghijkl
```

---

```
        for (int sum = 0; sum <= numRows + numColumns - 2; sum++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                int j = sum - i;

                if ((i >= 0 && i < numRows) && (j >= 0 && j < numColumns)) {
                    System.out.print(array[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

---

Can somebody point me in the right direction on how to fix my code to get the output that I want?

Comment: System.out.print(array[j][i]);

Comment: I tried that, but I get an ArrayIndexOUtOfBounds error

Comment: Ah, then, iterate i between 0 and numColumns and j between 0 and numRows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Traverse an array diagonally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346343/traverse-an-array-diagonally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it isn't very pretty, I think this will do it:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.println("" + array[i][j]);
    --i;
    ++j;
    if (i < 0) {
        if (j == numCols)
            break;
        i = Math.min(j, numRows - 1);
        j = Math.max(j - numCols + 2, 0); 
    } else if (j >= numCols) {
        if (i == numRows - 2)
            break;
        i = numRows - 1;
        j = Math.max(j + 2 - numCols + i, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry John.. Dont understand....To me the answer is not clear, What is the condition you are checking in While statement ?? and increment counters too seem bit oddly placed.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int n = 0;
int x = 3;
int y = 4;
int newSize = Math.max(x,y) * Math.max(x,y);

while(n < newSize){
    if(i <= x && j <= y)
        System.out.println(array[i][j]);
    n++;
    if(i == 0) {
        i = n:
        j = 0;
    } else {
        --i;
        ++j;
    }
}
```