# How do I traverse an array diagonally in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, matrix, iteration

I have an array with strings that I would like to traverse diagonally.
Assumptions:

- Each string is the same length.
- Arrays could be square or rectangular, horizontally or vertically.

The matrix looks like this:

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
```

I Would like to get (from top left to bottom right):

```
A
EB
IFC
JGD
KH
L
```

and (from the bottom left to top right):

```
I
JE
KFA
LGB
HC
D
```

I already have a piece of code that works 3/4 of the way, but i cant seem to figure out what I am doing (wrong).

```
//the array
var TheArray = ['ABCD','EFGH','IJKL'];

//amount of rows
var RowLength = TheArray.length;
//amount of colums
var ColumnLength = TheArray[0].length;
```

The code I have chops up the diagonals into 4 of these loops to get all the diagonals. It looks as 2 for loops with an if to not loop over unbound values. The pseudo code looks a bit like this:

```
for(loop rows){
 var outputarray = [];
   for(loop columns){
      if(delimit for out of bound){
       var temprow = TheArray[something?];
       var tempvalue = temprow[something?];
       outputarray.push(tempvalue);
       }
   }
 //use values
document.getElementById("theDiv").innerHTML += outputarray.join("")+"<br>";
}
```

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Are you using an array of "strings" or an array of arrays?

Comment: @goodguy5 it wouldn't matter because you can access string by index like arrays.

Comment: @jcubic precisely, It is an array with strings, not an array of arrays, and i am using the index to get the right value from the string.

Comment: Duplicate of homework questions: [Traverse an array diagonally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346343/traverse-an-array-diagonally) and [Traversing a 2D array matrix diagonally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835633/traversing-a-2d-array-matrix-diagonally-from-bottom-left-to-upper-right?lq=1)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### From top left to bottom right

```js
var theArray = ["ABCD","EFGH","IJKL"];

var length = { "x" : theArray[0].length, "y" : theArray.length };
length.max = Math.max(length.x, length.y);

var temp, k, x, y;

for (k = 0; k <= 2 * (length.max - 1); ++k) {
    for (temp = [], y = length.y - 1; (x = k - y), y >= 0; --y) {
        x >= 0 && x < length.x && temp.push(theArray[y][x]);
    }
    temp.length > 0 && (document.body.innerHTML += temp.join('') + '<br>');
}
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vu9tnjaL/))

---

### From the bottom left to top right

```js
var theArray = ["ABCD","EFGH","IJKL"];

var length = { "x" : theArray[0].length, "y" : theArray.length };
length.max = Math.max(length.x, length.y);

var temp, k, x, y;

for (k = 0; k <= 2 * (length.max - 1); ++k) {
    for (temp = [], y = length.y - 1; (x = k + y - length.y), y >= 0; --y) {
        x >= 0 && x < length.x && temp.push(theArray[y][x]);
    }
    temp.length > 0 && (document.body.innerHTML += temp.join('') + '<br>');
}
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/thkboe4r/))

---

### Combined

As there's but a single line of difference between both, you can easily combine them in a single function :

```js
var theArray = ["ABCD","EFGH","IJKL"];

function diagonal(data, fromBottom) {
    var length = { "x" : data[0].length, "y" : data.length };
    length.max = Math.max(length.x, length.y);

    var temp, k, x, y;

    var returnMe = [];

    for (k = 0; k <= 2 * (length.max - 1); ++k) {
        for (temp = [], y = length.y - 1; y >= 0; --y) {
            x = k - (fromBottom ? length.y - y : y);
            x >= 0 && x < length.x && temp.push(data[y][x]);
        }
        temp.length > 0 && returnMe.push(temp.join(''));
    }
    return returnMe;
}

document.body.innerHTML = diagonal(theArray).join('<br>') +
                          '<br><br><br>' +
                          diagonal(theArray, true).join('<br>');
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6udtavnx/))

Comment: If you run the snipped you will see that it missed entries from last column.

Comment: So close, i tried to implement your code and it seems alright, It works and I can understand what is happening. Thank you for that. But there is some problem when you have more rows in the array than the length of the strings. It does not return the last value. see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24xv3wvh/18/

Comment: @viperia : I just fixed that. Could you try again, with the code of my latest update?! ;-)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. That did it. The trick to see which side of the matrix is longer did it.

Answer (score 6):

This does the trick, and outputs the desired results to the screen:

```js
var array = ['ABCD','EFGH','IJKL'];
var rows = array.length;
var cols = array[0].length;
for (var n = 0; n < cols + rows - 1; n += 1)
{
  var r = n;
  var c = 0;
  var str = '';
  while (r >= 0 && c < cols)
  {
    if (r < rows)
      str += array[r][c];
    r -= 1;
    c += 1;
  }
  document.write(str+"<br>");
}
```

Result:

```
A
EB
IFC
JGD
KH
L
```

Comment: You may want to reverse the string using `str.split('').reverse().join('');`

Comment: This is basically the same as what I did. I think I like yours better, though. And you just made me realize that I was imagining the array wrong (flipped the indexes)

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution:

```js
function getAllDiagonal(array) {
    function row(offset) {
        var i = array.length, a = '';
        while (i--) {
            a += array[i][j + (offset ? offset - i : i)] || '';
        }
        return a;
    }

    var result = [[], []], j;
    for (j = 1 - array.length; j < array[0].length; j++) {
        result[0].push(row(0));
        result[1].push(row(array.length - 1));
    }
    return result;
}

var array = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL'];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getAllDiagonal(array), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use indices:

```
[i][j-i]
```

Where i goes from 0 to M-1

j goes from  0 to i

While j++ < N

for the matrix

type Array[M][N]

However this may miss a few at the bottom right if the matrix is rectangular, and you might need a second nested for loop with i and j to capture those.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var TheArray = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL'];
    //amount of rows
    var RowLength = TheArray.length;
    //amount of colums
    var ColumnLength = TheArray[0].length;

    var totalNoComb = RowLength + ColumnLength - 1;
    var combArr = new Array(totalNoComb);
    for (var i = 0; i < totalNoComb; i++) {
        combArr[i] = "";
        for (var j = RowLength-1; j >-1; j--) {
            if (i - j > -1 && i - j < ColumnLength)
                combArr[i] += TheArray[j][i-j];
        }
    }
    alert(combArr);

    for (var i = 0; i < totalNoComb; i++) {
        combArr[i] = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < RowLength; j++) {
            if (i - j > -1 && i - j < ColumnLength)
                combArr[i] += TheArray[ RowLength -1-j][i - j];
        }
    }
    alert(combArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try for 'from top left to bottom right':

```
for (i=0; i<nbRows; i++) {
    x = 0; y = i;
    while (x < nbColumns && y >= 0) {
        print(array[x, y]);
        x++; y--;
    }
    print("\n");
}
for (i=1; i<nbColumns; i++) {
    x = i; y = nbRows - 1;
    while (x < nbColumns && y >=0) {
        print(array[x, y]);
        x++; y--;
    }
}
```

Needs a few adaptations to fit JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This should work even for rectangular matrices:

```js
var array = ["ABCD", "EFGH", "IJKL"];
var arrOfArr = [];
var resultArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    arrOfArr.push(array[i].split(''));
}

var rows = arrOfArr.length;
var columns = arrOfArr[0].length;

var index = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    var k = 0;
    resultArray[index] = new Array();
    for (var j = i; j >= 0; --j) {
        resultArray[index].push(arrOfArr[j][k]);
        ++k;
        if ( k === columns) {
            break;
        }
    }
    resultArray[index] = resultArray[index].join('');
    ++index;
}

for (var j = 1; j < columns; ++j) {
    var k = rows - 1;
    resultArray[index] = new Array();
    for (var i = j; i < columns; ++i) {
        resultArray[index].push(arrOfArr[k][i]);
        --k;
        if ( k === -1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    resultArray[index] = resultArray[index].join('');
    ++index;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: This assumes that all strings are the same size, or at least are as large as the first string.

In a 2D array (or in this case, an array of strings), a diagonal's indexes add up to the diagonal's number (like a row-number). 00, 01 10, 02 11 20, etc.

Using this method, the number of diagonal "rows" (starting at zero) is equal to the sum of the largest indexes, or the sum of (columnlength+rowlength-2).

Therefore, my solution is to iterate through the diagonal row numbers and print all index pairs whose sum is equal to the current diagonal row.

```
var TheArray = ["ABCD","EFGH","IJKL"];
//amount of rows
var RowLength = TheArray.length;
//amount of colums
var ColumnLength = TheArray[0].length;

var text = ''
for (i = 0; i <= (RowLength+ColumnLength-2); i++){
    for (x = 0; x<=i; x++){
    if (TheArray[i-x] && TheArray[i-x][x]){
        text += TheArray[i-x][x];
    }
  }
  text += "<br/>";
}

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/HKhw8/1178/)

Answer (score 1):

Full solution for both diagonals:

```
var TheArray = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL'];
var RowLength = TheArray.length;
var ColumnLength = TheArray[0].length;

// Diagonals
var diagonal = [[], []];
for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(RowLength, ColumnLength); i++) {
    diagonal[0].push({'row': 0-i, 'col': i});
    diagonal[1].push({'row': 0-i, 'col': 0-i});
}

// Entry points
// 1///
// 2///
// 3456
var points = [[], []];
for (var y = 0; y < RowLength; y++) {
    points[0].push({'row': y, 'col': 0});
}
for (var x = 1; x < ColumnLength; x++) {
    points[0].push({'row': RowLength - 1, 'col': x});
}

// Entry points
// \\\6
// \\\5
// 1234
for (var x = 0; x < ColumnLength; x++) {
    points[1].push({'row': RowLength - 1, 'col': x});
}
for (var y = RowLength - 2; y >= 0; y--) {
    points[1].push({'row': y, 'col': ColumnLength - 1});
}

var strings = [[], []];
for (var line = 0; line < diagonal.length; line++) {
    for (var point = 0; point < points[line].length; point++) {
        var inside = true;
        var index = 0;
        var string = '';
        while (inside && index < diagonal[line].length) {
            var row = points[line][point]['row'] + diagonal[line][index]['row'];
            var col = points[line][point]['col'] + diagonal[line][index]['col'];
            if (row >= 0 && row < RowLength && col >= 0 && col < ColumnLength) {
                string += TheArray[row][col];
                index++;
            } else {
                inside = false;
            }
        }
        strings[line].push(string);
    }
}

console.log(strings);
```